# Can my MacBook Pro RAM be used in Lenovo U165?

Tags: memory, upgrade, lenovo-laptop, ddr3

I upgraded my MacBook Pro RAM to 8gb and now the original 4gb is unused. I want to use these to upgrade my Lenovo U165 RAM, which is only 2gb. Is this possible?

I also found out that both used DDR3 RAM as well. But are they compatible? My MacBook Pro was bought in 2010 and used Snow Leopard (already installed).

Comment: You'll need to list the specs of the RAM chips.

Comment: DDR3 RAM and 1333MHz

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, apple dosen't use non standard ram and you should be able to install it. If it was non standard, it would have a differerent pinout to prevent folk from using the wrong ram.

[image]

If it looks like the sodimm picture above from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM), it should probably work, assuming your chipset supports that amount of ram (which it should).